# Get height of div after content change in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get the new height of div after the content of the div changes? Using JQuery, this is easy, but I am having problems with this in vanilla javascript.

I tried to attach an event listener to the div, but it never gets triggered.

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('cookies-popup').getBoundingClientRect().height);
    });
```

The content of the div is dynamically changed after retrieved from the server. I tried to get the height with a callback after the http request is done, but the element.offsetHeight or the above command still return the old height when the div has no content inside.

The code that changes the content of the div:

```
this.staticPageService.getData('test').subscribe(payload => {
    this.divContent = payload.content;
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code who change the height of your div ?

Comment: The code changes the content of the div and consequently the height, it doesn't set a new fixed height.

Comment: Sure but I think the event "DOMContentLoaded" is not appropriate here. You maybe need to get the "height" after the change of the div. Can you post the code who change the div content ?

Comment: Done. this.divContent is the new content of the div which is then connected to the div using angular's [innerHtml].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After change the content of your div, you can call a function to get the new height of your div.

```js
this.staticPageService.getData('test').subscribe(payload => {
  this.divContent = payload.content;
  getHeightDiv('cookies-popup');
});


function getHeightDiv(idElem) {
  console.log(document.getElementById(idElem).getBoundingClientRect().height);
  return document.getElementById(idElem).getBoundingClientRect().height
}
```

### Update

I don't now what is `.divContent` but I think you can use `element.innerHTML` instead.

If you need to use `.divContent` try to use `setTimeout`.

```
this.staticPageService.getData('test').subscribe(payload => {
  this.divContent = payload.content;
  setTimeout(() => getHeightDiv('cookies-popup'), 100);
});


function getHeightDiv(idElem) {
  console.log(document.getElementById(idElem).getBoundingClientRect().height);
  return document.getElementById(idElem).getBoundingClientRect().height
}
```

Comment: It returns 0 as height.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious way for addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {}) using it as

```html
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})
```

not on single element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
let elem = document.getElementById('cookies-popup')
let ht = window.getComputedStyle(elem ).getPropertyValue('height')
```

Comment: I have tried that and it returns the old height when the div has no content. Maybe I have not placed it in the correct place.